# Count lines/characters between patterns using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I would like to count all the characters(ACGT) for each objects( here `GeneID:1`, `gi|479`, `nf|NZ_AC14`) so that I know the lenght of each of those object ( no need to count number of A, number of C..)

```
>GeneID:1
ATGCGTTTGCGTTTGCAAATCGACTAGCTTTTGGCCCAAAGCGTGCTGCAAAAGTATGGA
AGTAAAGCTACCGTACGTAGCTAAGCCTACCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACGCCCCCCCCC
>gi|479
ATGGATTGGATGGAATCACAATTCAAGACATGTACGCATGGCTGCGACTGGAAG
>nf|NZ_AC14
ATGGCTAGATATGTCGTATGTTGGATGTTCACCATCAACAATCCCG
```

I have multiple files like this and I would like to use a bash command so that everything is automated but I don't even know where to start to do this (mostly how I would count only after the line start with `>`)

The desired output would be :

```
>GeneID:1 121
>gi|479 54
>nf|NZ_AC14 47
```

but if I only have the number it's ok too.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v RS='>[^\n]+' 'oRT{gsub("\n","");print oRT,length()}{oRT=RT}'  file
```

The record separator is set to the gene name starting with `>`. All fields of the record are concatenated together by removing newlines. Then the length of the record is printed.

The variable `oRT` is set to capture the record terminator `RT` of the previous line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following `awk` command:

**INPUT:**

```
$ more input
>GeneID:1
ATGCGTTTGCGTTTGCAAATCGACTAGCTTTTGGCCCAAAGCGTGCTGCAAAAGTATGGA
AGTAAAGCTACCGTACGTAGCTAAGCCTACCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACGCCCCCCCCC
>gi|479
ATGGATTGGATGGAATCACAATTCAAGACATGTACGCATGGCTGCGACTGGAAG
>nf|NZ_AC14
ATGGCTAGATATGTCGTATGTTGGATGTTCACCATCAACAATCCCG
```

**COMMAND:**

```
awk '/^>/{if(NR>1){print tmp OFS l;} l=0; tmp=$0; next}{l+=length($0)}END{print tmp OFS l;}' input 
>GeneID:1 120
>gi|479 54
>nf|NZ_AC14 46
```

**Explanations:**

- `/^>/{if(NR>1){print tmp OFS l;} l=0; tmp=$0; next}` when you reach a line that starts with `>` you check that it is not the first line if it is the case you print the content of `tmp` and `l`; you initiate `l` at `0` and `tmp` at the content of that line
- `{l+=length($0)}` for other lines you count how many characters are present and add it to `l`
- `END{print tmp OFS l;}` when you reach the end of the file you print the content of the variables to treat the last group